# input value binding & observer not working in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I tried the code below

```
<input value="{{input}}">
```

input property inside javascript `Polymer({property: {}})`

```
input: {
    observer: "_input",
    type: String,
    value: "Z"
}
```

initially `<input>` show "Z" as its value but input property inside javascript `Polymer({property: {}})` is not updating with the change in the `<input>` & observer is not called

i tried this also but not working

```
<input bind-value="{{input}}">
```

How i do this in Polymer-1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is="iron-input"` & `bind-value="{{owner}}"` both are required

```
    <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{owner}}">
```

I found it from their doc [example](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it too if you write {{nameOfTheProperty::input}} inside the value like the next line:

`<input value="{{myValue::input}}">`

I think this way is better than iron-input because you don't have to import the iron-input element. You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-input